# How can I set the content of a outbout HttpResponse in Netty4?

Tags: java, http, netty

How can I add content to a [DefaultHttpResponse](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/DefaultHttpResponse.html)?. In Netty 3.x there was a `setContent()`-method. I could not find any details on how to use the HTTP classes in Netty 4. It seems like there are a few En/Decoders that can be used together with HTTP Packets but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either send a sequence of:

`HttpResponse , n * HttpContent, LastHttpContent`

of just use

`FullHttpResponse`

The `DefaultHttpContent`, `DefaultLastHttpContent` and `DefaultFullHttpResponse` take a ByteBuf as constructor parameter.

Comment: Wow, I wonder why I haven't seen this... Pretty simple. Thank you.